# Tab border in HTML/CSS (Beginner)

Tags: html, css

I am beginner and i am doing self study how to master this programing language html and css.

I have 3 columns in my body and I want a design like a tab border while the paragraph is inside in the box border. The color on the top of the border is blu (where can i put the tab name).

The picture below shows what I want to acchieve:
http://i58.tinypic.com/2i9gvt4.jpg

Comment: Do you have any Code samples by now?

Comment: i had no sample codes because i dont know how to start in html or css:(

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `<div>` container around your text, you can do something like:

```
<div>
    <!-- the "tab" -->
    <h3 style="color:blue;">ipsum</h3>
    <!-- the paragraph -->
    <p style="border: 1px solid black;">
        paragraph
    </p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Belonging the comment, here the new Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hqqtm2xf/2/

Remember to place the CSS styles in a seperate file, this is only for demonstration reasons.

For getting started in HTML and CSS i recommend http://www.w3schools.com/css/ and http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Hope it helps.
Greetings Mat

Answer (score 0):

You can also give each `<tr>`-Tag an own class and then set the bg-color there

```
<style>
.ipsum {

     color: #1062DD;
}

.paragraph {

    background-color: #333333;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: red;
    // height: 200px;
}
</style>
<table><td>
<tr class="ipsum">ipsum</tr>
<tr class="paragraph">paragraph</tr>
</td></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;">
<tr>
<td> Column1 </td>
<td> Column2 </td>
<td> Column3 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Just simplify the code.